# Form submit to iframe on new page

Tags: forms, redirect

I have a form which submits to an iframe, This works fine if you are on a page with the iframe.

I want to be able to have the form on any page and when submit is pressed load a page and send the submit to the iframe

e.g.

1. On page "article.php" and press submit
2. Open page "results.php" and
3. Send post data from form clicked in "article.php" to iframe "DataHere" on "results.php"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try detecting if the frame exists when the form is submitted and if it does not, reload the whole page and generate the iFrame.

If you need a hand checkout http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Check-Frames-Page-Script.phtml

Comment: Thanks, but how could I extend this to reload and resumbit the form to the iframe?

Comment: I suppose I'm asking how can i pass form data submitted on a page which has been loaded to an iframe

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to comfortably sanitize your initial `POST` data to avoid XSS, you could create an intermediate page for your iframe destination that does your `POST` for you:

1. On page `article.php` with `<form action="results.php">`, press submit.
2. `results.php` validates that the input isn't XSS, and renders with a `<iframe src="negotiator.php?my=form&data=here"></iframe>`
3. `negotiator.php` takes the query string arguments (and runs the same sanitizing as `results.php`) and `POST`s them to your intended url.
4. Your results will load in the iframe.

It's pretty important that you make sure your input isn't insane. If your form requires arbitrary text, punctuation, and special characters, this is *not safe* for you.